# How can I upload APK bigger than 100mb? (simplified)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, apk, augmented-reality

I've built an app using react native augmented reality app where the filters are located in the android app's assets folder but together those filters take up about 60mb or so, so when I build an APK from it, it always end up being bigger than 100mb. I've tried minifying it with proguard, getting rid of any unnecessary code and node_modules ... etc but it's just outright impossible to downsize the APK to be less than 100mb.

What are the ways of uploading it? I've looked online and people recommended that i need to create separate the android assets in expansion files. But what even are expansion files? and how do I create them? There are no clear instructions or guidelines that explain the fundamentals nor practicals.

Comment: You have generate split apk.

Answer (score 1):

Look into **Play Asset Delivery** (https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery). This solution has replaced the painful use of expansion files and allows to serve assets only when needed.

It can also make the download of your app faster by allowing the assets to be downloaded separately from the base of your app.